# App Store Connect TestFlight showing no builds

Tags: ios, testflight, app-store-connect

I'm trying to add a build to AppStore Connect but it's showing "No Builds" where should be an 'iOS' marker'

[image]

I have the same setup in another application and it's working just fine:

[image]

I have builds showing in the activity tab and it was working before.

Comment: I'm having this issue also. A ton of builds that were once there are now missing. Something weird must be going on Apple-side.

Comment: Same here! For context: I have an app that hasn't been through App Review yet that has this issue

Comment: @Rodolfo Which certificates did you used for uploading the build on app store. You should use distribution certificates and App Store provisioning profile for it.

Comment: I used distribution certificates, that's the strange thing, it was working before and there's no settings changed on the Bitrise

Comment: Our other apps are showing test flight builds just fine. The app we're having trouble with has not been through the App Store Review process, but we've had many builds go through test flight for it before with no issues. I read all of the TestFlight documentation to see if anything has changed, and it doesn't appear that anything has. I'm also not seeing too many people having this issue online either. I think the next step for me is to contact Apple Support, unless someone else has figured something out.

Comment: Already contacted, it's a pretty serious issue to us. In the meantime I've posted this here "just in case". After the issue is resolved, I'll post the answer bellow (if anyone does it first).

Comment: @RodolfoAntonici It's a serious issue for use too. Please provide an update when you hear back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem has re-surfaced from the start of April 2019. If you have exerienced this - this is how I solved it:

Existing Version 1.0.76

Changed this to 1.1.1 build and uploaded.

This appeared in activity pane (App Store Connect) and the Builds area of Testflight was filled with this 1 build. All 76 builds of v1.0 are still missing.

XCode 10.2

This has worked for the 3 Targets that were affected.

Hope this helps.

I was and still am waiting for Apple Support to reply to my week old Support query.

Thanks
John Goodstadt

Answer (score 2):

We are having this same problem at work, so one of our team members contacted Apple Support detailing our problem and this was their reply:

> Hello [Tyler's co-worker],
>
> Thank you for reaching out to us in regard to issues with your builds
>   not showing in your TestFlight section of App Store Connect. I
>   understand the importance of your request and I will be further
>   assisting you. My name is [Apple Support Person], I’m with Apple Developer Program
>   Support.
>
> I apologize for any inconvenience this has caused. Our engineers are
>   aware of this issue happening to developers. They are working on a
>   resolution. Currently, I don’t have an estimated time of when this
>   will be resolved. Feel free to reach out to me to check on any
>   updates. I’m more than happy to help in any way that I can.
>
> Your case number is [redacted].
>
> Best regards,
>
> [Apple Support Person]
>    Apple Inc.

So Apple is aware of the issue and is working on it, but there is no time frame for when it will be fixed.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't have any meaningful feedback from Apple yet, they asked me about 15 questions and I'm waiting for an update. Thanks!

Comment: Do you by any chance know, if the Apple team have solved it already?

Comment: @Keselme we haven't heard anything back from Apple yet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having this same issue too. I tried to increase the version number (not the build number) then re-up again. And it works.

Comment: Wow, I'll try it!