# TestFlight do not show any iOS Build

Tags: ios, testing, testflight, app-store-connect

I Have uploaded a new build on iTunes Connect using Xcode 10.2 and Application Loader 3.7.2 too.

The build is showing under activities:

[image]

But no build is showed under TestFlight IOS Builds:
[image]

I tried with many websites browsers (Safari, Google Chrome, ...) and clear website data too (after got the advice from Apple Support).

What should I do now? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Duplicate of [App Store Connect TestFlight showing no builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579067/app-store-connect-testflight-showing-no-builds)

Comment: Let's consolidate these duplicates. Clearly there's an issue at Apple's end.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your email inbox which you registered as apple account. There will be detail why apple removed your build. Mostly it happen due to, not added permissions in plist file like accessing microphone or photo library.

Comment: I did. The only email I received from Apple is something like this.

```
Dear ***,

The following build has completed processing:

Platform: iOS
App Name: **
Build Number: 6
Version Number: 1.0
App SKU:
App Apple ID: ********
You can now use this build for TestFlight testing or submit it to the App Store.
```

Comment: then wait for it. It will be on testflight or you will get another email from apple.

Comment: @MRizwan33 Wait for what? The OP got the expected email and the build should now be available to add to Test Flight.